# Which Rails active model association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

Trying to wrap my head around some ActiveModel association strategies.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. A `Quiz` belongs to a `Lesson`
2. A `User` can take a quiz (they don't own it)
3. The quiz score is saved and belongs to a user

So, I believe I'll need a `through` type table, such as `user_quiz_scores` that would provide me tracking information with the following columns:

- quiz_id
- user_id
- user_quiz_score

Assuming this thought process is correct so far, the Models would look something like:

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :quiz
end

class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lesson
end

class Score < ApplicationRecord
  has_many ??????
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scores
end
```

The Score model/table is really what I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.  Maybe I've overcomplicated this?  Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At a quick glance, it seems like it would be something like:

```
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :quiz
end

class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lesson
  has_many :scores
  has_many :users, through: :scores
end

class Score < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quiz
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :scores
  has_many :quizzes, through: :scores
end
```

Comment: As an additional suggestion, a `Quiz` `has_many :users, through: :scores`.

Comment: Thanks guys!  After looking at your suggestion, re-reading the docs, this now makes total sense!